# Difference b/w signing and encryption proprties in WAS

Tags: java, security, https, soapui, ibm-datapower

I am repeating this question again. I have java application runs in WAS server. Java calling Datapower via https. We have two properties files. 1. Message signing properties file contains: jks file name, password for jks file and directory paths for Request, response and fault.

2. Encryption properties file contains only SecretKey(AccessKey) which is = E0E97C2351A8925BBC454F25D676E026E0E97C2351A925B.

Actually this application developed other team and we maintaining and supporting it. In dev It is working fine.

We moved same code to SIT and same access key only change is different JKS file for SIT. We used same Accesskey. When we doing connectivity test in SIT, we are getting "AAA authorization error - RSA signature  did not verify" error on Datapower side.

When we test from soap ui using SIT jks file it is working fine. so my question is, is Access Key should be different in SIT? or am I missing anything ?

Please help?

Comment: Any help on this? or how Access key getting generated?

Comment: Friends. any clues in this..

Comment: Or, how to extract or decode signature value /digest value from soap security header?

Comment: RSA signature did not verify error in Datapower. any ideas?